# How to find out what stopped FileAppender rolling over properly

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

UPDATE: interestingly I only see below issue occurs in Windows environment, but in every Linux environment deployed it just working fine.

I have a Spring application (3.2) with Log4j 1.2.17 with fileAppender, here is the configuration

```
log4j.rootCategory=TRACE, ROL

log4j.appender.ROL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROL.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.ROL.File=C:/logs/spring-app/application-log4j.log
log4j.appender.ROL.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.ROL.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.ROL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -- %p -- %c -- %m%n
```

For some reason I found the log file sometimes stop rolling and grows very big so I add log4j debug mode

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

and I found following issue as symptom

this is when the logging process working fine

```
log4j: rolling over count=10332832
log4j: maxBackupIndex=10
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.9 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.10
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.8 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.9
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.7 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.8
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.6 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.7
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.5 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.6
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.4 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.5
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.3 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.4
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.2 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.3
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.1 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.2
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.1
log4j: setFile called: C:/STS/STS.3.2.0/logs/spring-app/application-log4j.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
```

And this is the start of appender failure

```
log4j: rolling over count=10332832
log4j: maxBackupIndex=10
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.9 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.10
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.8 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.9
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.7 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.8
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.6 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.7
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.5 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.6
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.4 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.5
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.3 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.4
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.2 to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.3
#Apparently fail the rename log.1 -> log.2
log4j: Renaming file C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log to C:\logs\spring-app\application-log4j.log.1
log4j: setFile called: C:/STS/STS.3.2.0/logs/spring-app/application-log4j.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
```

This issue makes older log (log.3 ~ log.9) gradually all went away by the rename and leave only the first one -- application-log4j.log. So this file can grow like crazy to 1 GB+, and no other logs generated.

But now i really don't have much method that can go in depth to find out what exactly going on that caused this issue (that the second log file failed to rename, seems like a log put on the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are known issues with `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` in log4j 1.2.17.  For example, the description for [this bug in log4j](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55621) looks similar to your problem.

You should be using the [rolling file appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) in `Apache Extras™ for Apache log4j™`, as it's [recommended in the Javadoc to do so](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html).  Here's a [link on Maven Central to the library](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17).

Have you tried the following configuration to see if it fixes your issue?

```
log4j.appender.ROL=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROL.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.ROL.File=C:/logs/spring-app/application-log4j.log
log4j.appender.ROL.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -- %p -- %c -- %m%n
log4j.appender.ROL.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.ROL.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000KB 
log4j.appender.ROL.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.ROL.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=C:/logs/spring-app/application-log4j.log
log4j.appender.ROL.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=C:/logs/spring-app/application-log4j.log.%i
log4j.appender.ROL.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex=10
```

Finally, log4j is an old library and not under active development.  You should strongly consider upgrading to log4j 2.0 if feasible.

Comment: thank you I really appreciate the advice. I tried the `Apache Extras for Apache log4j` but after two hours testing the log stop rolling over and keep growing in the first file. I am pretty sure there is no other thread running different instance of Log4j and no one open the log with windows notepad.

Comment: Another interesting factor, is that seems this issue only happens in Windows environment, never see the issue occurs in any Linux environment. So it seems like Log4J doesn't work well with the timing during I/O in windows.

Comment: One the other hand, is there any release notes that states in certain version of Log4j that such RollingFileAppender issue is fixed? I couldn't find related doc to know which version exactly fix it. Changed to Log4j2 is expensive with good amount of code change so just want to see a doc somehere states that the issue is resolved by certain version of Log4J?

Comment: @Dreamer yes, this is a known issue on Windows.  One workaround is to use a time based policy to create a unique file name on rollover.  See http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/RollingFileAppender-not-working-consistently-tp8582p8594.html